# My app crash everytime I add code to dismiss keyboard - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app with xCode and I have a numberPad / decimalPad that I need to dismiss when the screen is tapped anywhere. is a single text input on all the screen. I saw online and I got this code below on viewDidLoad:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Next I added this func after the viewDidLoad

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

For some reason, I tried different ways, but the app crashes when tapping on the screen after insert the value on the textfield.

Been looking online everywhere, but nothing seems to fix this issue.

I would add a Done button and a toolbar too, but xCode gives me errors and because I'm still learning can't figure it out yet.

I'm running the last version of xCode and coding with the last Swift version available to date.

Any suggestions?

Complete crash log:

> 2020-08-16 10:17:16.734232-0400 Melitus[10862:586552] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 25764_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default 2020-08-16 10:17:16.767685-0400 Melitus[10862:586552] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 25764_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default 2020-08-16 10:17:18.229188-0400 Melitus[10862:586552] -[Melitus.ViewController carbsLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc99f07b70 2020-08-16 10:17:18.240444-0400 Melitus[10862:586552] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Melitus.ViewController carbsLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc99f07b70' *** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23e3de6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff512539b2 objc_exception_throw + 48 2 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23e5eb94 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132 3 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49354af0 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 302 4 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23e4286c forwarding + 1436 5 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23e44b58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120 6 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49326c1d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83 7 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48cd5baa -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223 8 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48cd5ef2 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 396 9 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49632d69 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 155 10 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49353dae -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 358 11 UIKitCore 0x00007fff496329af -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 48 12 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49353f10 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 275 13 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49632829 -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 93 14 UIKitCore 0x00007fff4964b0da -[UIView(UITextField) endEditing:] + 184 15 Melitus 0x000000010012311d $sSo16UIViewControllerC7MelitusE15dismissKeyboardyyF + 205 16 Melitus 0x000000010012316b $sSo16UIViewControllerC7MelitusE15dismissKeyboardyyFTo + 43 17 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48eb6358 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 44 18 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48ec02ba _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109 19 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48ebcb89 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 295 20 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48ebbeda -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureForActiveEvents] + 760 21 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48ead9cb _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 2745 22 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48eaced4 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 467 23 UIKitCore 0x00007fff48eacc5c -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 225 24 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49364277 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4479 25 UIKitCore 0x00007fff4933e6d1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356 26 UIKitCore 0x00007fff493c94ce __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 7628 27 UIKitCore 0x00007fff493cc692 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6584 28 UIKitCore 0x00007fff493c2f35 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 88 29 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23da1c91 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17 30 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23da1bbc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76 31 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23da1394 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180 32 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23d9bf8e __CFRunLoopRun + 974 33 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404 34 GraphicsServices 0x00007fff38c39bbe GSEventRunModal + 139 35 UIKitCore 0x00007fff49325968 UIApplicationMain + 1605 36 Melitus 0x0000000100128a2b main + 75 37 libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff520ce1fd start + 1 38 ??? 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: Thread 1: Exception: "-[Melitus.ViewController carbsLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9953e0ae70"

Comment: That's the error xCode presents me when tapping anywhere outside the keyboard or when pressing the Done button on the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Update 2: I'm adding a sample for Xcode-playgrounds for you to try out, try to make your code as similar to the following code or make the below code similar to your to reproduce the issue.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()
    }
}
extension UIViewController {
    func setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView() {
        let tapOutside = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        tapOutside.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapOutside)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        print("dismissing...")
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ViewController())
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Update: The crash you're getting is probably due to conflict between an existing method with the same name. Try renaming the method:

```
@objc func dismissMyKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

You should be using `#selector` instead of `String` as the argument for `action` parameter.

Replace:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
```

With:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissMyKeyboard))
```

Comment: I also tried the way you suggested. It also happens the same thing. And yes, I tried to add @objc at the func after viewDidLoad. 

I don’t understand the reason this is happening.

Comment: I don't have any other method with an even close name to that one. This is teh error xCode gets me when the app crash: Thread 1: Exception: "-[Melitus.ViewController carbsLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9953e0ae70"

Comment: I didn't say it's your method. It's a UIKit method. Did you even try the solution?

Comment: I did! even created an extension with completely different names and it still happens. tried multiple different codes I found online and it dows happen the same thing with all of them with the same error. Tried even add a done button and a toolbar and it did happen too.

Comment: I've added the complete crash log to the discussion, so would be easier to analyze what is happening.

Comment: Make sure you've changed the `var tap` declaration as I've updated above.

Comment: extension UIViewController
    {
        func setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()
        {
            let tapOutside: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                target: self,
                action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))

            tapOutside.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tapOutside)
        }

        @objc func dismissKeyboard()
        {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

Comment: That's the extension I have right now. I guess would do the same as what you suggested above? Both crash the app.

Comment: You still haven't changed the name of the method as I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: extension UIViewController
    {
        func setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()
        {
            let tapOutside: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                target: self,
                action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissMyKeyboard))

            tapOutside.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tapOutside)
        }

        @objc func dismissMyKeyboard()
        {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

Comment: Even with dismissMyKeyboard instead of dismissKeyboard, it will crash!

Comment: Try: `UIViewController.dismissMyKeyboard` -> `dismissMyKeyboard`

Comment: Still crash even if I remove the UIViewController.dismissMyKeyboard and replace with only dismissMyKeyboard

Comment: What I found out is that if I remove the line view.addGestureRecognizer(tap) from the code, the app won't crash, but the keyboard won't dismiss.

Comment: Ok, so I've added a sample for you to try out on code playgrounds check it out and try to figure out what's different in your code that's causing this issue.

Comment: I tried to apply the sample code on playgrounds. I only get a white screen, which I assume that's suppose because there's nothing on the code except the code you provided. Tried even copy the same code to my project and the crash still happens. I think I need someone to look into my code in detail and try to find out why this is happening. If anything is found.

Comment: I assume is something with xCode itself, but I think is way too unlikely that I am the only person on the world with this type of issues. I have other elements on my app, like a slider and labels and other Controller Views and everything else is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to do it.

- Add tap gesture in viewDidLoad func (Use selector instead of string)

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

- Try using `resignFirstResponder`

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: I will try this solution as soon I arrive at home, I'll let you know if it works with me! Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Let me know if it helps or not

Comment: It made the app crash too. I really don't understand what the hell is going on!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed finally!

So I was tired of trying different codes and decided to erase the TextField that I previously had and create a new one with a different name. For my surprise, this fixed the issue and allowed me to do what I had to do. The keyboard is dismissed as soon I touch anywhere on the screen as is suppose to without crash the app.

Thank you so much all of you that were trying to solve my problem!

I'll leave this up so if anyone is passing thru the same thing, may try to do the same thing as me or see the other answers.